# Using for loop to print out multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a program that prints out 100 square divs (using a loop) each with a different random background color.

It goes through the loop because it finds 100 different colors(in the console)
But it only makes one square.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>That's a Lot of Div</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="box" ></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    let box = document.querySelector("#box");
    box.style.float = "left";
    box.style.height = "50px";
    box.style.width = "50px";
    box.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    console.log(box.style.backgroundColor);
}


function randomColor() {
    var r = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
    var colorString = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    return colorString;
}
```

It prints a single square div that changes color each time you refresh the page instead of 100 square divs.

Comment: *"But it only makes one square."* There is only one div on your page, `#box`. If you want multiple ones you have to create them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: "*I'm trying to create a program that prints out 100 square divs*" - but at no point do you, or your code, create any one of those `<div>` elements. What did you expect to happen with the code that you've shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lauren, see below, some changes to create the elements.

Notice we `appendChild` and we `createElement`. Each `div` is an object and must be created.

```js
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    // We need something to add our new element too
    let target = document.querySelector("#target");
    // Now we have to create a NEW element
    let box = document.createElement('div');
    // Removed the float for the answer as they will stack on top other wise.
    //box.style.float = "left";
    box.style.height = "50px";
    box.style.width = "50px";
    box.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    // Now we add it to our target
    target.appendChild(box); 
}


function randomColor() {
    var r = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
    var colorString = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    return colorString;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>That's a Lot of Div</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n = prompt("Enter the number");

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  
    let target = document.querySelector("#target");
    
    let box = document.createElement('div');
  
    box.style.float = "left";
    box.style.height = "50px";
    box.style.width = "50px";
    box.style.marginLeft="20px";
    box.style.backgroundColor ="red";
   
    target.appendChild(box); 
}
```